# How to influence Here Maps autosuggest results

Tags: autosuggest, here-maps-rest, heremaps

We are using the Autosuggest API to autocomplete user requests for regions. When searching for "Nordsee" (North Sea in German)

```
    https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?q=Nordsee&limit=10&resultType=place&lang=de-DE&in=countryCode:DEU&in=circle:50.9277386,11.5944852;r=600000&apiKey=<apiKey>
```

we would expect a suggestion for a bounding box or a position at North Sea but get a position for the restaurant with the name 'Nordsee' somewhere in Germany. We get a similar result for 'Ostsee' and some other regions. (whereas for states in Germany, e.g Bavaria or Hessen, it works as expected)

```
{"items":[{"title":"Nordsee","id":"here:pds:place:276u301x-db8fb4e0b1f84414bec4bdc665692300","resultType":"place","address":{"label":"Nordsee, Markt 23, 07743 Jena, Deutschland"},"position":{"lat":50.92772,"lng":11.5876},"access":[{"lat":50.92778,"lng":11.58761}],"distance":483,"categories":[{"id":"100-1000-0000","name":"Restaurant","primary":true}],"chains":[{"id":"1938"}],"references":[{"supplier":{"id":"core"},"id":"1070632188"},{"supplier":{"id":"tripadvisor"},"id":"1342109"},{"supplier":{"id":"yelp"},"id":"dbXYlvzodqeQaYHfl5U45A"}],"foodTypes":[{"id":"800-075","name":"Fisch und Meeresfrüchte","primary":true}],"highlights":{"title":[{"start":0,"end":7}],"address":{"label":[{"start":0,"end":7}]}}}],"queryTerms":[]}
```

We wondered if we can influence the results of the autosuggest API in some way e.g. by

- adding own POIs or regions
- prioritizing regions over places or adresses
- somehow else to achieve the expected result

Thanks for your time and effort. Chears.